# Rewrite rule not working good

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to change some thing in htacces, i'm trying to do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*).xml$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]{2})\. [OR] [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ sitios/es/$1 [L]
```

if i change RewriteRule to something like this works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ sitios/es/something [L]
```

i guess that the problem it's in $1 because i receive internal error
What may i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your rules create an infinite loop.

For example, if I visit `ab.example.com/anything.xml`:

- The `%{REQUEST_URI}` is `/anything.xml` which matches `^/(.*).xml$` and the parenthesis would match `anything`.
- The `%{HTTP_HOST}` is `ab.example.com` which matches `^([^.]{2})\.` and the parenthesis would match `ab`
- The second condition for `%{HTTP_HOST}` also matches, since `ab.example.com` is not an empty string (`^$` matches empty strings)
- And finally, the RewriteRule matches the request URL-path (which is `anything.xml`) against `^(.+)$` which is OK, and the parenthesis (referred to later using `$1`) contain `anything.xml`

So, my request for `ab.example.com/anything.xml` gets internally redirected (since you have no `R` flag) to `ab.example.com/sitios/en/anything.xml`, which also matches ([see why](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)) all the rules above, so it would get internally redirected to `ab.example.com/sitios/en/sitios/en/anything.xml`, which also matches and so on and so on...